# Could not authenticate you

Tags: iphone, twitter

under the message is my code. But I have taken error message "Could not authenticate you"

how can I fix it ?

thank you

```
- (IBAction) sendButtonTapped: (id) sender {
    NSString* themessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@. I'm %@ and feeling %@ about it.",
                            notesField.text ? notesField.text :@"", 
                            [activities objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]],
                            [feelings objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSLog(@"Twett buttone tapped ");

    //TWITTER BLACK MAGIC
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://user name:password@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@", themessage] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error;
    NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]);

    //END TWITTER BLACK MAGIC

}
```

Comment: Could you try to remove status parameter? 
In C# project, I remove status parameter and it works

Answer (score 0):

To call twitter web service APIs you gotta use OAuth, read about it [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)